# How to add text with replace function and regex?

Tags: regex, excel, replace

I am working on excel and I need to add text at the beginning of some cells.

Let's say I have the following cells :

```
IO
KP
HU
IO
```

I would like to replace them by :

```
5IO
5KP
5HU
5IO
```

So I select those cells and use the find and replace function. In search i put "*" but what I am supposed to put in replace in order to keep the text returned by * ? It would be "5SOMETHING".

Comment: Are you replacing all cells (ie appending 5 to each one), or just ones that match certain text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `Find and Replace` is flexible enough to do what you want i.e. append `5` to each cell.

The simplest way would be to use this formula to create a new column and then delete the original. [ *I'll assume your data are in column A* ]

```
=5 & A1
```

You could also do it through VBA if you like.

```
Sub AppendFive()
    Dim cl As Range

    For Each cl In Range("A1:A10")
        cl = 5 & cl
    Next cl
End Sub
```